# running r.execute() from Java in a for loop

Tags: java, jess

I have written a code in JESS. I am now running the code from Java. I have run to this problem that I want to have the engine.execute("") command in a for loop. 
My example code is :

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
r.executeCommand("(answer(ident headers.get(i)(text patientData.get(j).get(i))");
    }
}
```

where answer is a deftemplate in JESS with two slots. I am reading a text file in Java and inserting the values in the slots of the deftemplate.

Thanks,
Ali

Comment: you haven't actually asked a question, or provided any information about what error you're having. Please provide more information on exactly what the problem is.

Comment: Well, for starters, you can't use variable names in string quotes, because that will print the literal name, not the value. You need to use the string concat operator to build a string containing variables. Ex: `"(answer(ident headers.get("+i+")(text patientData.get("+j+").get("+i+"))"`

Comment: sorry, I didnt add the problem, The whole phrase in the command will be treated as a string , while the headers.get() is a variable in Java. using the concat doesnt seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `answer` is a deftemplate with slots `ident` and `text`, the following snippet looks like the construction of a fact:

```
(answer(ident headers.get(i)(text patientData.get(j).get(i))
```

- A bare fact does not represent a Jess command that can be executed via `Rete.executeCommand`.
- You shouldn't use the deprecated method `executeCommand`; use `eval`.
- Your parentheses aren't balanced properly, 6 opening parentheses against 4 closing ones.
- Assuming that headers is a `List<String>` in your Java application, you cannot simply throw a Java method call at Jess, which doesn't understand Java syntax in the first place and (presumably) doesn't know about the pojo `header` at all.
- The same is true for the pojo `patientData`.
- While you might pass *objects* from your Java program to the Jess engine, this is absolutely impossible for simple variables like `i` and `j`.

Considering all of this (most of which is easy to learn from the excellent Jess manual), using

```
r.eval( "(assert (answer (ident \"" +
        headers.get(i) +
        "\")(text \"" +
        patientData.get(j).get(i) +
        "\")))" );
```

might have a chance of succeeding and indeed insert a new fact into working memory.

Comment: Thanks for the response Laune, I have inserted the facts now. 
Rules do fire in my .clp file, but I cannot assert deftemplates in the .clp file. Is there anything I have to do in addition for each rule and assert I want to make? 
Thank you very much
Ali

Comment: The assert function call as it is built in the eval call in my answer can also be used in a CLP file: `(assert (answer (ident "123")(text "some data"))` should give you a fact.

Comment: Only one rule in the .clp file will be fired even though the facts should fire more rules. Do I have to add anything to make all the rules fire?
Thanks

Comment: Certainly not. - You might post a new question showing the rules you expect to fire and the data you insert.